# Ionic/Cordova - update PACKAGE_NAME in platforms/android.json and platforms/ios.json

Tags: android, ios, xml, cordova, ionic-framework

Is there a way to do this without deleting and re-installing the platforms directory?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm trying to generate two APKs with different bundle IDs -- one for Development and one for Production.  The bundle ID is being read correctly from the config.xml file at the root of the project and updated in the `<manifest>` tag.  However, I have the cordova-push-plugin installed which requires an android:name XML attribute of the form `PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE` and the bundle ID part of this property is not being updated with the bundle ID found in config.xml.

It looks like the Cordova build process for Android looks at the `PACKAGE_NAME` property in the `platforms/android.json` file and uses that to insert permissions into the AndroidManifest.xml file.  Is there a way to update this?

edit: I'm using Ionic to build my project and use the `ionic state reset command` to delete/add the platforms back.

Comment: I would try this way: Duplicate your project and just use a text editor and do some search & replace.

Comment: @Android Noob, as Joerg suggests, this would be a way to try. However, sometime, it is quicker and easier just to start over.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that Sublime Text takes a long time to do a project-wide replace for some text.